# How to stream a file in rxjava without affecting memory

Tags: java, java-stream, filestream, vert.x

I have a requirement like below.

1. My application need to call an api which returns the response as binary data (pdf or image files < 30MB).
2. Once I receive the binary response, I need to prepare a json object with some other elements and call 2nd api(this api doesn't support streaming) to process the request.

The concern here in the step1, If I get a big file like 10 or 20MB of binary data, the server memory is getting occupied. I can't able to stream once I read the file in step1 to step2 as the 2nd api doesn't support streaming. What are the options we have to consume less memory and send the json to the 2nd api? We are using vert x & Reactive java. Please suggest.

Comment: I don't think there are **any** other options.  Apart from changing the requirements or constraints.

Comment: That depends on how you receive your response and whether the JSON construction can begin without the whole completed response from API1. If not, there is no other way - you **have to** store the whole first response in memory.

Comment: The JSON construction with other elements are already available before calling step1, but only one element depend on the response from step1. The step2 api expects all the elements together.

Comment: How do you send the binary file in the JSON payload to 2nd API, base64 encoded? Which client do you use, `HttpClient` or `WebClient`? Please add some snippets or the question remains to vague to be answered correctly.

Comment: yes we do base64 encoded and we use rxjava webclient.